# Invalid procedure call or argument vba. Run time error 5

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I try to select only one file but I have .AlloMultiSelect = True There is an error message saying: Run-Time error '5':Invalid procedure call or argument and highlights "strPathAndSparks = .SelectedItems(2)". So my question is if I can enable multiselection and pick only one file, if so where is my mistake in this lines of code. This is what I have. I thank you all in advance.

```
 strInitialDirectory = CurDir
 Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 With fd
    .Title = "Choose Jira File"
    .InitialFileName = CurDir & "\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"

    If .Show = False Then
        ChDir (strInitialDirectory)
        Exit Sub
    End If

        strPathAndJira = .SelectedItems(1)
        strPathAndSparks = .SelectedItems(2)
 End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs if the user selects 1 or fewer items.  You cannot *compel* the user to select 2 items, but you can test how many items *were* selected with

```
fd.SelectedItems.Count
```